# Vertical stepper with table content

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, mui-datatable

I am currently in a pickle with a component I want to make.
It is a mix of a vertical Stepper component and a Datagrid.

As you can see below, I want to group certain table sections within a vertical Stepper content.
This is purely a component for data visualization, so do not worry about any logic attached to each component. The stepper should also always have all steps expanded.

Do you have any idea how to proceed with this problem?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am writing the application in React (typescript) using MUI v5 pro.
[image: Design]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  You want to have a vertical stepper with the step content to contain a data grid?  Do you have some code with your issue that we can work off of?

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear... 
I do not have any code or the like because I simply do not know how to tackle this yet. 
My question is more on how you would implement this, not necessarily as code but more as a direction to proceed.
I just want my finished result to look like the image above, but if it actually should be a data grid as a step content, I do not know

Comment: So, just to clarify, there will be a vertical stepper on the left and the data grid on the right will change what is displayed when the stepper changes? Do each of the data grids have the same columns or are they different data grids for each stepper selection?

Comment: Not really, the datagrid on the right will always be a static content. The problem is that I wanted to divide the rows of the table into sections that should be "grouped" under a step.
My consideration at this point is just to create a kind of hidden column that displays the stepper icons and then insert an empty row to simulate the space between sections. 
Since I don't really need the stepper functionality, but just the visual look of it

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: this response is opinion-based)

I would begin by getting an MUI stepper to behave like you would want.  It appears that you want to use something like `Tabs`, but have them look like a `Stepper` component.

There are several directions I would personally take.  Namely, modifying a `Tab` component to look like a `Stepper` or modifying a `Stepper` component to behave like a `Tab`.  I chose the later option as I started working on this in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-stepper-to-control-data-n0zbt0?file=/demo.tsx).

Second, I would create a `DataGrid` section of the page that would change based on the state of the previous component.  The CodeSandbox example showed a basic behavior with text.